# tracking multiple objects using calcOpticalFlowPyrLK

Tags: c++, opencv, video, computer-vision

The below code of snippet is for tracking but the problem is i don't know why for some reasons the points(centroid points of object) disappears for few frames parallely calcOpticalFlowPyrLK is also  not working for those frames everything disappears for few frames. Images are as shown below. Can anyone Please help to track these objects continuously. I also tried to do with kalman filter but couldn't succeed.

Frame 10 of the video

[image: Frame 10 of the video]

Frame 25 of the video

Look at this image points disappears just an input image is displayed

[image: Frame 25 of the video]

Frame 45 of the video

[image: Frame 45 of the video]

```
    for(int i =0; i<theVehicles.size(); i++){
    Point p=Point(theVehicles.at(i).getXPos(),theVehicles.at(i).getYPos());
    points12.push_back(p);
    TermCriteria termcrit(TermCriteria::COUNT|TermCriteria::EPS,20,0.03);
    Size subPixWinSize(10,10), winSize(31,31);

    //cout<<p;

   calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prevGray, filledEdgesOut,  points12,points, status, err, winSize, 3, termcrit, 0, 0.001);

   RNG rng(12345);

            for( int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++ )
     { 
         circle( frame, points[i], r, Scalar(rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255),rng.uniform(0,255)), -1, 8, 0 ); 

         /*cv::circle(frame,points[i],10,cv::Scalar(0,0,255));
         cv::putText(frame,intToString(theVehicles.at(i).getXPos())+ " , " + intToString(theVehicles.at(i).getYPos()),cv::Point(theVehicles.at(i).getXPos(),theVehicles.at(i).getYPos()+20),1,1,Scalar(0,255,0));
    cv::putText(frame,theVehicles.at(i).getType(),cv::Point(theVehicles.at(i).getXPos(),theVehicles.at(i).getYPos()-30),1,2,theVehicles.at(i).getColour());*/
            }

    }
```

Comment: @Miki Can you please look at this problem once is there anyway i can solve ??

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in a loop (for each frame for example) then you have to re-generate the points on the object once it's detected and tracked correctly. For example, if you are using a bounding-box to describe your vehicles then once you match a vehicle between two consecutive frames you have to generate a new set of points by using *good features* or uniformly on the new detected vehicle.

Comment: i have done either ways sir..!! but still the problem persists. Look at the first image and last image of the question above two vehicles in the middle are detected separately but in the third image they both merge to form single objects. The points are not being tracked. And result is also not reliable like in the second image of the above results are not displayed.